# How to add and remove CSS classes based on validation errors on client side?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Regarding .net core mvc, how do I add and remove classes for `<span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName">` based on a validation error or even between different errors?

```
            <div class="form-group offset-sm-2 col-sm-8">
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="control-label register-heading-style"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control form-control-valid rounded-0" placeholder="John" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" id="FirstNameError" class="text-danger form-control-invalid invalid-bg"></span>
            </div>
```

Is there a way in JS perhaps to check for errors on input (the errors that are automatically displayed under `asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName"`)?

Thank you

Comment: You could replace the `IHtmlGenerator` service, and override `GenerateValidationMessage`, as that is called from here; https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs#L96. Though it does look like you can control the css class name (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1a4db562c4b9cfba2b18de3aad1ee4b1847716d0/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L858)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change class by different error. I think you can't change class per one error. but i think is better use `[TempData]` and use specific span and show each one when that value is not empty.or null. for this approach you must validate what you need and feel `[TempData]`  for that.

for example:

```
if(TempData["error"]!=null)
{
<span>this is an error</span>
}
if(TempData["success"]!=null)
{
<span>this is susccess</span>
}
if(TempData["warning"]!=null)
{
<span>this is warning</span>
}
```

Comment: How would I have TempData when the error is triggered on user input change?

Comment: my best solution is genarate span value by key. for example: in controller side return "VALID-E", in your front-end set an eventLisener when getting that key in span value, change with your own Sentence and own class you whant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo about if the span which id is `Input_FirstName-error` has error infomation,add class `customClass` to it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#FirstNameError").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
                if ($("#Input_FirstName-error").length > 0 && $("#Input_FirstName-error")[0].innerText != "") {
                    $("#Input_FirstName-error").addClass('customClass');
                }
                
            });

        });
```

result:
[image]